# How do I configure styles and layout of a Summary Link Web Part using code?

Tags: web-part, feature, feature-activation, features

I have successfully added a Summary Link Web Part as a feature and want to configure the styles and layout of it, including:

1. The default style for new links
2. The group header style
3. The number of columns for groups

I would also like to add two new groups to the web part.

I need to do this when installing the web part as a feature during deployment.

Any leads would really help.

Answer (score 4):

Simillarly as with Content Query Web Part (CQWP) also the Summary Link Web Part is governed by an XSL file in charge of rendering content available at the Site Collection Level in the Style Library called SummaryLinkMain.xsl.

I would strongly recomand simply copy that file, rename it to your liking and then export your SLWP and change its attributes to point to the new file.

Beyond that you would need to change default CSS classes for more controlled rendering in accordance with your branding requirements. You could use a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to insert your CSS into page dynamically.

Comment: can you please share a sample custom SLWP.webpart that would point to a custom itemstyle.xsl. I tried your suggestion but the XSL property of webpart keep defaulting.

Comment: I got it after little bit of googling, http://www.theroks.com/add-custom-styles-to-summarylinkwebpart/